# BigQuery Query from terminal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terminal, google-bigquery

I've a multi-table that came from a sink between logging and bigquery and I'm trying to exec this query from my terminal to get the results locally (for export it, because I can't add new SA or other stuff).
So this's the query:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=true \
'
  SELECT
    timestamp AS Time,
    logName AS Log,
    textPayload AS Message
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mytable.stdout_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'MONTH'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))
'
```

It's working perfectly fine on GoogleCloud website, but unfortunately when I'm trying to exec it in my terminal it give me that error:

> Error in query string: Error processing job 'mytable_0000017e01909804_1': Timestamp evaluation error: (L2:1): SELECT query which references non constant fields or uses aggregation functions or has one or more of WHERE, OMIT IF, GROUP
> BY, ORDER BY clauses must have FROM clause.

How I can fix it?

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can upvote or accept the answer. This can help future users who are having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery supports two SQL languages: StandarSQL and LegacySQL. In this case, I’m using StandarSQL. To use this language, I set this flag to false `use_legacy_sql=false` because some commands and syntax are different between each other (StandarSQL and LegacySQL).

Here, you can see more [information](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) about this flag.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
'
 SELECT  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([myproject:mydataset.people],
                   DATE_ADD(DATE (CAST(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE))),
                   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
'
```

You can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#functions) about the commands of legacy that BigQuery supports.

[image]